# Dealing with structs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm using the Fuzzy Logic Toolbox and exporting the FIS to the workspace (for plots and so on). The exported FIS is a 1x1 struct with all the information about the fuzzy system and I'd like to work with that inside the editor (.m) but I don't know how to do that. I've tried some functions to load variables from workspace  but they haven't worked well.

Has somebody already done something similar?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What does "work with that inside the editor" mean? What exactly have you tried? And why didn't it work well? Your chances of getting help will increase if you provide some meaningful information. See also: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @dasdingonesin, I want to build a .m file to manage with all the struct information. When you export a file from Fuzzy Logic Toolbox to workspace it generates a struct, and this struct is what I want to 'load' in a .m file.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'load'. The struct is already in your workspace, so you can perform any operation you like on it, either via the console or by running an M-file. Can you tell me what _exactly_ you're trying to achieve? "Manage with all the struct information" is extremely vague, I really don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd recommend you to have a look at this [documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/working-from-the-command-line.html). I think everything is explained or linked to the corresponding documentation. If we have no more information about what *exactly* you want to do, it's not going to be possible to give a good answer.